# How to get rid of extra space after resizing Drawer in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, navigation-drawer, whitespace

I resized my sample MUI drawer with a specific width. The problem I have now is that I have an extra space left after resizing my drawer, thus leaving out my text contents of lorem ipsum with a "margin-like" space. I want to make the text to be close to the drawer as much as possible even after resizing the drawer. To sum it up, I want to remove this remaining space but I'm not sure where to edit it in terms of box or containers.

MUI drawer resized:

[image: Space]

Extra space that needs to be deleted (highlighted lines by Pesticide chrome extension):
[image: Extra space]

Drawer sample source code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Drawer from "@mui/material/Drawer";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import AppBar from "@mui/material/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "@mui/material/Toolbar";
import List from "@mui/material/List";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";
import ListItem from "@mui/material/ListItem";
import ListItemButton from "@mui/material/ListItemButton";
import ListItemIcon from "@mui/material/ListItemIcon";
import ListItemText from "@mui/material/ListItemText";
import InboxIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoveToInbox";
import MailIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Mail";

const drawerWidth = 240;

export default function Test() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <CssBaseline />
      {/* STACK-OVERFLOW  (done tweak on toolbars)      <AppBar
        position="fixed"
        sx={{ width: `calc(100% - ${drawerWidth}px)`, ml: `${drawerWidth}px` }}
      >
        <Toolbar>
          <Typography variant="h6" noWrap component="div">
            Permanent drawer
          </Typography>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>                  --- removed HEADER*/}
      <Drawer
        sx={{
          width: drawerWidth,
          flexShrink: 0,
          "& .MuiDrawer-paper": {
            width: drawerWidth,
            boxSizing: "border-box",
          },
        }}
        variant="permanent"
        anchor="left"
      >
        {/* <Toolbar /> */}
        <img
          id="marseeysicon"
          src="images/marseeys-icon.png"
          alt="Marseeys Icon"
          class="center"
        />
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["Inbox", "Starred", "Send email", "Drafts"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
        <Divider />
        <List>
          {["All mail", "Trash", "Spam"].map((text, index) => (
            <ListItem key={text} disablePadding>
              <ListItemButton>
                <ListItemIcon>
                  {index % 2 === 0 ? <InboxIcon /> : <MailIcon />}
                </ListItemIcon>
                <ListItemText primary={text} />
              </ListItemButton>
            </ListItem>
          ))}
        </List>
      </Drawer>
      <Box
        component="main"
        sx={{ flexGrow: 1, bgcolor: "background.default", p: 3 }}
      >
        {/* <Toolbar /> */}
        <Typography paragraph>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
          eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Rhoncus
          faucibus et molestie ac.
        </Typography>
        <Typography paragraph>
          Consequat mauris nunc congue nisi vitae suscipit. Fringilla est
          ullamcorper eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam. Pulvinar
        </Typography>
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

CSS drawer resize source code:

```
   .MuiDrawer-paper {
 width: 10% !important;
 }
```

Your responses would indeed help me a lot as I am exploring MUI currently.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, remove CSS:

```
.MuiDrawer-paper {
  width: 10% !important;
}
```

And update this line:

```
const drawerWidth = 240;
```

It can be "200px" or "10%", whatever you need.

Comment: Ohh, this is the first const in my drawer sample code. Literally didn't noticed that this can be tweaked. Thus, I edited this just now and it definitely worked in getting rid of the space! Thank you very much for the response @user4980215

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect elements, you will see

```
<div class="MuiDrawer-root MuiDrawer-docked css-1f2xuhi-MuiDrawer-docked">
  <div class="MuiPaper-root MuiPaper-elevation MuiPaper-elevation0 MuiDrawer-paper MuiDrawer-paperAnchorLeft MuiDrawer-paperAnchorDockedLeft css-12i7wg6-MuiPaper-root-MuiDrawer-paper">
```

`.MuiDrawer-paper` does not change the width of the parent element, which is `240px`

```
.css-1f2xuhi-MuiDrawer-docked {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 240px;
  -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
  -ms-flex-negative: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh I see, so are there any ways to override this parent element so that I can adjust its width?